# How to deal with large objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, webforms, business-objects

I have 5 types of objects: place info (14 properties),owner company info (5 properties), picture, ratings (stores multiple vote results), comments.

All those 5 objects will gather to make one object (Place) which will have all the properties and information about all the Place's info, pictures, comments, etc

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a page that displays the place object and all it's properties. another issue, if I want to display the Owner Companies' profiles I'll have object for each owner company (but I'll add a sixth property which is a list of all the places they own)

I've been practicing for a while, but I never got into implementing and performance experience, but I sensed that it was too much!

***What do you think ?***

Comment: What exactly are you asking for here? Opinions?

Comment: Yh, I want to know if these kind of objects are large ? .. is my design flawed and how to deal with that!

Comment: 14 properties in an object is no big deal. In some complex scenarios you will find many more than this.

Comment: Ok, imagine the comments object have a text of 500 characters and you have like 50 comments, this is just one object of the 5 objects that will make up the place information .. more over if I loaded like 9 of them in a list in an Owner profile object .. do you think it's still okay !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to examine the use case scenarios for your solution. Do you need to always show all of the data, or are you starting off with displaying only a portion of it? Are users likely to expand any collapsed items as part of regular usage or is this information only used in less common usages?

Depending on your answers it may be best to fetch and populate the entire page with all of the data at once, or it may be the case that only some data is needed to render the initial screen and the rest can be fetched on-demand.

In most cases the best solution is likely to involve fetching only the required data and to update the page dynamically using ajax queries as needed.

As for optimizing data access, you need to strike a balance between the number of database requests and the complexity of each individual request. Because of network latency it is often important to fetch as much as possible using as few queries as possible, even if this means you'll sometimes be fetching data that you do not always need. But if you include too much data in a single query, then computing all the joins may also be costly. It is quite rare to see a solution in which it is better to first fetch all root objects and then for every element go fetch some additional objects associated with that element. As such, design your solution to fetch all data at once, but include only what you really need and try to keep the number of involved tables to a minimum.

Comment: I can partition the UI to display each object's info in a separate tab .. but my DAL and BLL populates the object with full information (all it's objects) .. what design could I use to fetch only the required data ? should load each object on it's own when needed ?  .. N.B although I can partition the information into tabs I'll need the access to be fast to all the other objects as they are all likely to be viewed (not equally but most likely)

Comment: @IKashef Edited answer to include some data access guidelines.

Comment: @IKashef It sounds like you intend to use your domain entities (aka objects) directly in your views. This is generally a bad idea. Use specific custom-tailored view model classes to hold just the information you need, such as PlaceViewModel with just the properties of the Place entity needed for rendering the UI. You can find lots of questions/answers here related to MVC and view model design considerations.

Comment: @lKashef If performance becomes an issue, you can use different fetching strategies for different use cases of your Place object, each loading only required data. And you can rely on an old trick called caching.

Comment: @driushkin. Thanks I'll take my road to it's end and if I faced any problems I'll try to learn performance testing and caching .. Hope it's the way to go!

Comment: @Morten Mertner. I didn't notice your edit, I'll read it and reply but @ur other comment, Yh! I'm using entities for like every table in my database and let my DAL to fetch them and place them in the object/entity and the BLL validates the object and sends it in a List<Entity> if they are more than one, otherwise I just send the object (say the place object) to the UI .. your advice "Use specific custom-tailored view model classes" isn't quite clear for me because I didn't learn much about other patterns and it sounds like a good idea but is it hard to implement this with webforms ?

Comment: @Morten Mertner. So (it's better to fetch all the data about the place and include everything the page needs) rather than (fetching the initial amount to get the first page started and then fetch the required data for every tab when needed ?) .. if you may check this follow up question concerning my data access technique, that would be great http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213171/sql-selecting-from-multiple-tables-in-one-query-or-a-query-for-each-table ..+1

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 issues to deal with really, and they are often split into DAL, BLL and UI

Your objects obviously belong in the BLL and if you're considering performance then you need to consider how your objects will be created and how they interface to the DAL. I have many objects with 50-200 properties so 14 properties is really no issue.

The UI side of it is seperate, and if you're considering the performance of displaying a lot of information onto a single page you'll consider tabbed content, grids etc.

Tackle it one thing at a time and see where your problems lie.

Comment: I didn't get what you want to say about the DAL part .. but yh I'm afraid that they will be a lot to load onto a page at once, so I thought about tabbed content like you suggested but I don't know how will I implement this into my BLL (N.B I have business objects layer and business logic layer)

Comment: The DAL is the Data Access Layer i.e. your SQL queries or Stored Procedures. If you're consdering how you'll display the data in the UI there are a number of options available to you and all depend how you want to display the data. Have a look at the Telerik objects, they're very useful

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear, I know what a DAL is but I don't what you meant by "consider how your objects will be created and how they interface to the DAL" .. hmm, so what are my options ? please check my comment on Morten Mertner's answer and if you need to know anything else please let me know! =) Thanks cusimar