# SQL: Selecting from multiple tables in one query or a query for each table?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, performance, database-design

A follow up question concerning the DAL layer part .. The first question about [dealing with large objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210579/how-to-deal-with-large-objects)

I have one table (PlacesTable) that is connected by like 6 other tables (1:Many and Many:Many relations)

In my DAL should I put a big query that join the 6 tables + the m:m reference tables (btw it produces multiple data that I don't need  [Please refer to my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391933/complicated-database-manipulation)) and place all the data in it's specific object property or, should I use a single query for each table and create an object for each fetched table .. and finally send those to the UI ?

If I wasn't clear enough please let me know what I further information do you need to know!

Thanks in advance for your time and help =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off with a single query returning all the information required for the UI.

Each database connection will be slow and you will have to wait for all of them to finish before having your data ready for the UI.

The slowest thing between the application and the SQL server is the act of establishing connections - the less of them, the better.

Comment: @Oded. but with the size of such a query full of joins, plus it returns duplicate rows so it will be a lot of data to fetch and a lot of code to remove the duplications .. could you please refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391933/complicated-database-manipulation so you could get the whole picture!

Comment: @IKashef - I did read through that question already. Unless you are talking about megabytes of data more over the table by table approach, it is better to return all the data in one go.

Comment: @Oded. Thanks =) .. just to make everything clear, so all the joins and the duplications and adding additional class and methods with a lot of loops and condition checks to remove the duplications are worth it ?

Comment: @IKashef - I can't tell you if it is worth it. Depends on what is most important to you (performance vs code bloat). I can tell you that it will generally be faster and more performant to get the result of a join than running multiple queries.

Comment: @IKashef - Note that I didn't say you have to make _any_ joins. You can use a single stored procedure with 6 selects to return all of the data without duplication.

Comment: @Oded. I'm sorry I got a little confused! do you suggest me to have a single stored procedure that includes 6 or any number of select statements I need or use a single join statement cause you mentioned the "join" more than once in your answer .. btw the data's going to be megabytes in a year and I need to have a scalable application but yet I don't want to lose the users' satisfaction with my website!

Comment: @IKashef - I didn't mention the word `join` once in my answer. I did say that you should get as much data in one connection as possible. One way of doing that is joins, another is a stored procedure with many selects. You should do whatever of these that returns less amount of data (while still having all the required data) and which is cheaper for the database to perform.

Comment: @Oded, Excuse me -My bad!- .. Thanks a lot for the help =) .. I think I'll go with the stored procedure for now and avoid the joins and later I'll try to implement it using joins and test the difference!

Comment: @IKashef - I just wanted to add that using join doesn't mean you _have_ to duplicate data. It depends on how they are written and what data you are returning. Of course, every situation is different, so I don't know if this is possible for you.

Comment: @Oded. well I've written the details in the question I refereed to before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391933/complicated-database-manipulation .. If you think there's a better way to write it to avoid duplications that would be great! =)

Answer (score 2):

If one big query gives too much duplicate data, and 6 round trips are slow... some options

- Use a stored proc to return 6 recordsets in one DB call
- Do some joins on the server to reduce both duplicate data and roundtrips

  - do both

Have you any performance differences yet? Or is this guess driven optimization?

Comment: actually this is a guess driven, and I wanted to see the opinions of people of a wider experience to stop me if I'm heading the wrong road!

Comment: btw what did you mean by joins on the server !?

Comment: @lKashef: JOINs in *SQL* server, instead of in your client code

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it! .. could you give me an example !?

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be about whether you should load related entities into your Places object. It sounds like you've got a few classes in your model, which is a great start.

Load only the data you require. Consider your consumer(in this case, the UI). Do you need to display this data? Only query for the data you need. Build multiple methods in your DAL to ensure that the right data is loaded at the time. i.e. `GetPlacesSummary()` returns your data shaped one way, while `GetDetailedPlaces()` returns a more granular data set.

Look into a data access component that supports *lazy loading*. This means that only when you access those properties (like Customer.Invoices.Count) will the data actually be queried from the database.

Comment: your answer fits into my original question and it's good .. but my question here is if I already decided to load information at once .. should I retrieve it using a single query that joins all my tables or use a single query for each table that will all run in the same method and finally they will populate the Places Object (Note: the places is an object with multiple List<T> of my other entities like, comments, owner's info, pictures (only paths) and actually my big concern is the owner's info object which will have a List<Places> property!!)

Answer (score 0):

In general, the database performs much better at joining data from several tables than other technologies. You will get better performance if you make one query than if you make several queries. You will also get the added benefit of not having to have a one-to-one relationship between your tables and your objects.

Comment: If it was about the connections maybe I could batch query my database and run all the queries in one connection but if you could refer to my comment on Oded's answer you would understand some other bad sides for single one query in my case .. "You will also get the added benefit of not having to have a one-to-one relationship between your tables and your objects." could you clarify this sentence a little bit please! =)